# Was bedeutet "he cheated on me" auf Deutsch?

Tags: meaning, english-to-german

Gibt es im Deutschen umgangssprachliche Ausdrücke für:

1. die dritte Frau/den dritte Mann, die/der eine Beziehung zerstört?
2. ein anderes Wort für "fremdgehen" ("er geht fremd" - Wie kann man noch anders sagen?)
3. "He cheats on me" bedeutet "Er hat mich betrogen". Bei uns sagen wir, wenn ein Mann betrogen wird, dass er 2 Hörner auf dem Kopf hat.
4. "Er wurde betrogen" - bei uns wird "er wurde rausgekickt" gesagt.

Gibt es auch Umgangssprache/Jugendsprache dafür?

Comment: Was ist denn jetzt die Frage? Wird hier gleich die Übersetzung von einer ganzen Liste von Ausdrücken gesucht?

Comment: Willkommen bei German language SE! Könntest du die Überschrift bitte so ändern, dass sie die Fragen zusammenfasst, die du hast? Im Moment wird die Frage in der Überschrift schon in deinem Text beantwortet (wobei: "Er betrügt mich" wäre richtig).

Comment: Wer ist mir "uns" gemeint, wenn du "bei uns" sagst?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Nebenbuhler**
   Das Verb *»buhlen«* bedeutet, dass jemand um die Gunst oder Zuneigung einer anderen Person wirbt. Es kann auch verwendet werden, um zu beschreiben, dass jemand um eine Sache oder eine Chance konkurriert. (*»Er buhlt um ihre Aufmerksamkeit«*.) Davon abgeleitet sind die Substantive *»der Buhle«* und *»der Buhler«,* die beide für den Geliebten einer Frau verwendet werden können. (*»Sie hat sich einen Bankdirektor zum Buhlen genommen.«*) Diese Wörter werden heute aber nur noch selten verwendet. Das Wort *»Nebenbuhler«* findet man hingegen auch heute noch gelegentlich. Es bezeichnet einen Mann, der (durchaus auch erfolgreich) versucht, eine Liebesbeziehung mit einer Frau einzugehen, die sich offiziell in einer Verbindung mit einem anderem Mann befindet. Das kann natürlich zum Zerbrechen dieser offiziellen Beziehung führen, es gibt aber auch viele Fälle, wo die offizielle Beziehung weiter besteht.
2. **ehebrechen, betrügen, untreu sein, Ehebruch begehen**
   Der Nebenbuhler, der von außen zu einer bereits bestehenden Beziehung hinzukommt, geht nicht fremd. Er ist auch nicht untreu und er betrügt niemanden (außer er hat selbst bereits eine andere Beziehung). Nur wer sich bereits in einer Beziehung befindet, kann fremdgehen oder den Partner betrügen. Das gilt übrigens für Männer und Frauen gleichermaßen. Wenn die beiden miteinander verheiratet sind, spricht man auch von Ehebruch. Auch dann, wenn die Ehe trotzdem weiter fortgeführt wird.
3. **dem Mann die Hörner aufsetzen, »der gehörnte Mann«**
   In Italien wird ein betrogener Mann als *»cornuto«* bezeichnet, was auf Lateinisch *»cornutus«* (gehörnt) zurückgeht, denn von gehörnten Männern kann man schon in antiken Schriften lesen. Damit ist eine Geste verbunden, bei der in Hüfthöhe die Hand zur Faust geballt wird, bei der der Zeigefinger und der kleine Finger ausgestreckt werden und die Hand so gedreht wird, dass die Finger nach oben zeigen. Dabei führt man mit der Hand eine stoßende Bewegung nach oben aus. Diese Geste wird gelegentlich als *»Doppelphallus«* bezeichnet und die Geschlechtsteile der beiden Männer darstellen, mit denen die Frau eine Beziehung hat. Gleichzeitig erinnert diese Geste an die beiden Hörner eines Tieres mit Hörnern (Bock, Ochse). Es gibt Vermutungen, dass mit den Hörnern die Geilheit der Böcke dargestellt werden soll, andere Quellen sehen darin eher den Hinweis auf einen kastrierten Ochsen. Was genau man vor mehr als 2000 Jahren, als diese Geste und die Bezeichnung entstanden sind, gemeint war, lässt sich heute nur mehr schwer feststellen.
4. Da ich nicht weiß, wo "bei uns" ist, kann ich dazu nichts sagen. Das Wort *»kicken«* ist ein Lehnwort, das erst nach ca. 1960 aus dem Englischen in den deutschen Wortschatz aufgenommen wird. Das Wort hat im Deutschen daher keine große Tradition und kommt in keinen Sprichwörtern vor. Es wird hauptsächlich im Zusammenhang mit Fußball verwendet. Das deutsche Wort dafür ist *»treten«,* wobei *»treten«* mehrere Bedeutungen hat. Aber keine dieser Bedeutungen hat etwas mit betrügen zu tun.

Umgangssprachlich sind mir keine Abweichungen gegenüber den gerade genannten Begriffen bekannt.

Jugendliche sind nur für wenige Jahre jugendlich. Daher ist das Vokabular der Jugendsprache oftmals weniger als ein Jahr lang aktuell. Echte Jugendsprache wechselt ihren Wortschatz so rasch, dass jeder Versuch, ihn zu erfassen bevor er wieder veraltet ist, zum Scheitern verurteilt ist. Wenn der eine oder andere Begriff, der in der Jugendsprache entstanden ist, sich dennoch länger als wenige Jahre hält, gehört er nicht mehr zur Jugendsprache, sondern ist ein Neologismus.

Comment: "kicken" bzw. "gekickt" wird auch als eine Art Fachausdruck für das Rauswerfen eines Benutzers verwendet, z.B. bei Chat-Gruppen oder (Online-)Computerspielen. Diese Bedeutung wäre auch auf Beziehungen übertragbar.

Comment: Aber wenn man jmd. aus einer Zweierbeziehung kickt, ist sie nicht mehr. Man kickt sich damit selbst mit raus. Es passt daher nicht.

Comment: 3. Wird das denn in Deutschland verwendet? Ich kenne den italienischen Brauch, aber in Deutschland scheint mir das gänzlich unbekannt und unverbreitet.

Comment: @Bodo Das habe ich auch schon so gehört, ala "Mein Partner hat mich rausgekickt" für "Mein Partner hat mich rausgeworfen". Allgemeinhin wird darunter das Beziehungsende verstanden (mindestens aber die Auflösung des gemeinsamen Wohnverhältnisses).

Comment: "Buhle" bzw. "Buhlschaft" gibt es maskulin *und* feminin.

Comment: Vielen lieben Dank für eure Antworten